# When use linearization method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$ x'_{1}  = x_{2} + x_{2}^3$$ 
$$ x'_{2} = -x_{1} -  x_{1}^3 $$.  show that origin is stable but not asymptotically stable. Can linearization method be use in this case?

Comment: This question is much better than your previous. First, which are your definitions of stability, asymptotic stability?

Answer (score 0):

The linearized system at the origin is
$$x'_1=x_2
,\qquad
x'_2=-x_1
,
$$
which is a centre, making linearization useless. (There's no way of saying from this what effect the *nonlinear* terms might have; even a tiny perturbation make destroy a centre, in either a stable or an unstable way.)

Instead, try to find a constant of motion: $dx_2/dx_1 = x_2'/x_1' = \cdots/\cdots$, etc.

Comment: The constant of motion (or first integral) exists here, so you could have said that it will only lead to Lyapunov unstable or stable but not asymptotically stable equilibria :)